# Parsing JSON with eval

Tags: javascript, json

I have this code:

```
function useHttpResponse() 
{

 if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 )
 {
 var response = eval('('+xmlhttp.responseText+')');
  alert(response);
 for(i=0;i<response.Users.length;i++)
        alert(response.Users[i].UserId);

 }
}
```

When i alert, the first alert is "[object Object]"

Why is that so? I need to remove that...how?

Answer (score 1):

Decoding a JSON string converts it into a native JavaScript object.  When you `alert()` it, the object's `toString()` method is called to cast the object back to a string.  Any object cast to a string becomes `[object Object]`.  Consider the following example:

```
var myObj = new Object();
alert (myObj);            // alerts [object Object]
alert (myObj.toString()); // alerts [object Object]
alert (({}).toString());  // alerts [object Object]
```

If you want to JSON encode the object again, you can use the `JSON.stringify()` method found in modern browsers and provided by [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js).

```
var myObj = {"myProp":"Hello"};
alert (JSON.stringify(myObj));    // alerts {"myProp":"Hello"};
```

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that so?

Because that is what you get when you convert a simple object to a string.

> I need to remove that...how?

Delete `alert(response);` from your source